# Jquery 'permission denied' error for JSON call between HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: jquery, json

I have a login control on my homepage (http://www.xyz.com) which makes a JSON login request over HTTPS (https://www.xyz.com/json.ashx). This seems to work fine in Firefox and IE7. But IE8 gives a 'permission denied' error for jquery.min.js

I have verified that this call works fine if its solely over http or https.

Is the call considered 'cross-domain' if it is between the http and https sections of the site? How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks,
Murali

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To illustrate 'cross-domain', the following table gives the overview of typical outcomes for checks against the URL "http://www.example.com/dir/page.html".
[alt text http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/7650/crossdomain.gif](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/7650/crossdomain.gif)

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to use the same control to login from both the http and https sections of my site. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe it would be considered cross domain, or cross protocol. Can you load in the script from the https domain, even if you're looking at the http domain. I have a feeling that might work.(competely untested just a hypothesis).